Nuxt3 yarn dev missing styles
Nuxt3 yarn dev missing styles, but prod mode exists(yarn build & node .output/server/index.mjs).
the issue I commit is here https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/29311
the reproduction is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zwhk6w?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.vue
my code here https://github.com/krmao/nuxtjs/tree/pc
git clone https://github.com/krmao/nuxtjs.git
git checkout pc
yarn install --check-files
yarn dev

after yarn dev
please visit on http://localhost:3000/  and will see that no style such as 'root-container' not in html
I have tried all ways such as upgrade nuxt version but not work, any one can help me?

The issue key founded https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/29311 remove vite vue options in nuxt.config.ts, will resolve the issue.
